# How can i get the cost of resources in a resource group in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have tried the following

```
foreach ($resource in $resources) 
{
  $resourceId = $resource.ResourceId
 $cost = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -Scope $resourceId  -StartDate (Get- Date).AddMonths(-1) -EndDate (Get-Date) | Measure-Object -Property PretaxCost -Sum |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum

    Write-Host "Resource: $($resource.Name)"
     Write-Host "Cost: $($cost)"

}
```

But the error is that
"A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Scope'."

How can I do this ?

Comment: Well, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.billing/get-azconsumptionusagedetail?view=azps-10.1.0 has no `-Scope` argument

Comment: then how do we know which cost we are getting for which resource ?

Comment: every time i call the above i get the error:     Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Comment: @Mel - To understand more why you are getting Operation return an invalid error Just Run `Get-azConsumptionUsageDetail -debug` cmdlet you will see the complete error message. As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/), cost management supports only for EA subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get the cost of resources in a resource group in Azure using Powershell?

In the `Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail` command, there is no `scope` parameter. However, the `scope` parameter is available in the `Get-AzCostManagementExport` command

I also tried to execute the same command that you tried to get the `resource group` usage details, but I am getting the same error as you.

[image]

Here is the update command for checking **Resource group** cost using **PowerShell**.

```
$RG=Get-AzResourceGroup
$DaysBack=30
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysBack)
$endDate = (Get-Date)
foreach($RGgroup in $RG.ResourceGroupName){
Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -ResourceGroup $RGgroup
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Refer:  [Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.billing/get-azconsumptionusagedetail?view=azps-10.1.0) and  [Get-AzCostManagementExport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.costmanagement/get-azcostmanagementexport?view=azps-10.1.0)

Comment: I still get Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'  . I ran with -debug and got "Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version. Please use api version after 2019-10-01

Comment: The -scope parameter in Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail command is not supported, kindly use Get-AzCostManagementExport command to use the -scope parameter.